# WebSocket Realtime REST-API client with Java

Tags: java, api, rest, websocket

So I've created REST API end-point by using spring framework,
most of the end-points that I've created is using Spring WebSocket, which means I need to create real-time API request from the client-side,
It's pretty easy to use Web Socket on the javascript client-side, but I have no idea how to create Java Client-side to handle that.

Is anyone can give me some example project or code, how to build real-time WebSocket API requests by using Java? just plain java, not using any framework. just basic examples I guess, like how to set up the end-point URL, header, send JSON as body request, handling request data, handling request error, etc

Edit :
I found an example but its Javascript client side :

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8000';
function connectToSocket(gameId) {
    console.log('connecting to the game');

    let socket = new SockJS(url + '/gameplay');

    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    stompClient.connect({},function (frame) {
        console.log('connected to the frame: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe(
            '/topic/game-progress/' + gameId,
            function (response) {
                let data = JSON.parse(response.body);
                console.log(data);
                displayResponse(data);
            },
        );
    });
}
```

is there any equivalent code that I can use in java? thankyou.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.